# How to Convert Get request to Post request in WebApi?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, kendo-grid

I want to change GET request in WebApi to POST request because I need to send data in the body of post request.

This is in js:

```
    $scope.DS = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            type: "json",
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/api/Employees/GetAllRecord",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    type: "GET"
                },
```

I changed type to be Post:

```
type: "POST",
```

The following is in webApi:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "Employees/GetAllRecord")]
    //[HttpPost] 
public IHttpActionResult GetAllRecord([FromBody] Models.DataSourceRequest request)
    {

            if (request != null)
            {
                var s = request;
            }
            var user = db.Users.Select(x => new RegisterBindingModel()
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                Email = x.Email,
                UserName = x.UserName,
                FirstName = x.FirstName,
                LastName = x.LastName,
                Age = x.Age,
            });

            var a = user.ToList();
            var b = Json(new { Data = a, Total = a.Count() });
            string strserialize = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(b.Content); // b.Content have json data
            //var c = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RegisterBindingModel>>(b.ToString());
            MyData c = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyData>(strserialize);
            return Ok(c);
            //return user.ToList();
        }
```

This the RegisterModel:

```
public class RegisterBindingModel
{

    [Display(Name = "ID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "FirstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Lastname")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Age")]
    public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

And I faced an error (see Attached picture)
So, To fix this I create new model as the following:

```
public class MyData
{
    public List<RegisterBindingModel> Data { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
}
```

I ran the project and from Fiddler I noticed that the request called twice:

First call as **/api/Employees** which have all the records.

Second call as **/api/Employees/GetAllRecord** which have 400 bad request
and its error message is:

*Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[Project.Models.RegisterBindingModel]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path '', line 1, position 2.*

Here is the format of strserialize:

```
 {
"Data": [{
    "Id": 1,
    "Email": "Test@gmail.com",
    "UserName": "Test",
    "FirstName": "Test",
    "LastName": "Test",
    "Age": 23,
    "Phone": 1234560987
}],
"Total": 13
   }
```

Now, How can I fix this?

And please could someone tell me Why does Webapi executing twice?
Is this normal ? Or Is there something I did wrong?

**UPDATE**
I think I have to do this from frontend,
I tried the following:

```
       parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                    debugger;

                    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(options.models));
                        return JSON.stringify(options.models);
                    }
                    else {
       //  var filters = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(options);
                        var a = angular.fromJson(options)
                        return JSON.stringify(a);
```

[image]

Comment: You need to changed WebGet to WebInvoke with type POST in the service contract. If it's allready using WebInvoke change it's type to POST.

Comment: I tried both of them [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/Employees/GetAllRecords")] ,,,,, and  [HttpPost] ,,, and no change

Comment: If I used [HttpPost] I got Message=The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.

Comment: As the error suggests, you are incorrectly deserialzing your JSON to what is required. What does your  `RegisterBindingModel` look like? And from the looks of it your deserialization would be `var c = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RegisterBindingModel>(b.ToString());`

Comment: @RahulSharma Thank you for your response, I already tried this which gave an error and I fix it by creating new model, Could you please check the question again ? it's updated.

Comment: @A.Han What does your `string strserialize = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(b.Content);` look like?

Comment: {
     "Data": [{
    "Id": 1,
    "Email": "Test@gmail.com",
    "UserName": "Test",
    "FirstName": "Test",
    "LastName": "Test",
    "Age": 23,
    "Phone": 1234560987
      }],
   "Total": 13
     }